# Transformar a dato numerico una parte de string

Tags: java, array, ordenamiento

como están?, me explico tengo que un arraylist que me viene con valores como "1valor","3valor", "2valor","4valor", mi intención es ordenarlo, pero no se como, ocupe el Arrays.sort pero por que le me fijo solo sirve para datos numéricos, entonces no se como mas hacerlo :/, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Buenas, por favor agrega el codigo que tienes de momento, para saber que estás haciendo. La idea es realizar un [mre] para comprobar tu codigo.

Comment: leiste la documentacion? sort permite ordenar desde objetos hasta casos particulares si le decis como...

Answer (score 0):

> mi intención es ordenarlo

Para ordenar un `ArrayList` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```java
List<String> valores = new ArrayList<>();

valores.add("1valor");
valores.add("3valor");
valores.add("2valor");

Collections.sort(valores);
```

Puedes entrar en esta pagina para ver otras formas de ordenarlo https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-sort-arraylist-in-java/

> ocupe el Arrays.sort pero por que le me fijo solo sirve para datos numéricos

Aquí tienes una confusión. Siendo que tienes un ArrayList, que es una implementacion de `List` no puedes usar `Arrays.sort`, debes usar `Collections.sort`. Aquí puedes ver la [diferencia](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-arrays-and-collection-in-java/) entre Arrays y Collections.

Answer (score 0):

como tu arraylist es de tipo string puedes usar funciones de tipo substring para conseguir solo el valor que quieres en este caso es el valor de indice 0, guardar hacer una comparacion de estos con un if

```
   String valor = "1valor";
   valores.add(valor);
   String valor_a_sacar = valor.substring(0);
```

posteriormente parsear 'valor_a_sacar' a entero y hacer las comparaciones de los 3 valores que se parsearon con if's